# excel userforms combobox with values from RowSource: how to update .Value following an update of the .Text?

Tags: vba, excel, automation

An Excel UserForm I have to work with has a combobox. Its RowSource is a 2 columns range (property `Text` coles from column 2, property `Value` coles from column 1).

When I change the `text` by clicking on the combobox (on the form), `value` gets updated, but when I set `.Text` property in VBA code, `.Value' value does not get updated. How to force the vba code to replicate the manual behaviour? Thanks.

```
Public Sub generalSettingsForm_MyCombo(ByVal newValue As String)
    generalSettingsForm.MyCombo.Text = newValue
    Call generalSettingsForm.someUnrelatedButton_Click ' some code
    Call generalSettingsForm.MyCombo_Change ' some code
    Dim str As String
    srt = generalSettingsForm.RatingModelCombo.Value
End Sub
```

Firing some update event would be the best option, but VBA context menu does not have anything remotely similar to that.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "RowSource is a 2 columns range". I tried to replicate what you did. When I use a single column range as the RowSource, everything works as you would like. Why are you using two columns - you seem to want "value" returned to be different than the text shown?

Comment: One column contains a user-friendly text values, the other contains the ints ("codes") used by the spreadsheet. I cannot change the spreadsheet, and am trying to change the userform code as little as possible, because this is not my project. Thanks again for looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code to the form. When you double click on the text box, you will see a new (empty) event created - you can add code there to change the combobox value when the .text is changed.

Comment: What I tried (see the code in my question) does not work, maybe I was trying the wrong things?

Comment: You need to change the value of the combobox - it doesn't work in both directions. So if you want to change it by passing a string, you need to look up what value that corresponds to, and set the value.

Comment: You are saying that it is impossible to automate this lookup even though it does happen when I chanage the text manually (with the click of the mouse button)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (this code is in a regular module):

```
Sub demoUpdate()
    With UserForm1
        .ComboBox1.Text = "this"
        MsgBox "text is now " & .ComboBox1.Text
        MsgBox "value is now " & .ComboBox1.Value
        .Show
        MsgBox "value is now " & .ComboBox1.Value & "; text is " & .ComboBox1.Text
        .ComboBox1.Text = "that"
        MsgBox "text is now " & .ComboBox1.Text
        MsgBox "value is now " & .ComboBox1.Value
        .Show
        MsgBox "value is now " & .ComboBox1.Value & "; text is " & .ComboBox1.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

The `rowSource` in my case is a single column wide... And I did specify a `controlSource` as one of the properties of the comboBox. I could not see what you are seeing with a dual column - for me, the combobox is only responding to the first column when the `rowSource` range is two columns wide...

Comment: The vakue gets updated when the combobox loses focus (or so it seems).